# Xampp not showing echo text

Tags: php, linux, apache, xampp

Xampp seems to be running fine, status says php is running, I am able to access the localhost  xampp status website and do phpinfo there and it look good.

It also work to run a php script that change a websites background image.

but its not possible to echo some strings...

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

returns: Hello World '; ?>

```
<?php
    $name='Harry';
    echo $name;
?>
```

returns nothing, all blank.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

returns nothing, all blank.

```
<?php print(Date("l F d, Y")); ?>
```

returns nothing, all blank.

I am accessing the file like this:

```
http://localhost/dummies/helloW.php
```

source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>PHP test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 

<?php
    $name='Harry';
    echo $name;
?>


<?php phpinfo(); ?>

<?php print(Date("l F d, Y")); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

What could cause this problem ?

ACCESS_log

127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2014:14:54:56 +0200] "GET /xampp/perl.pl HTTP/1.0" 200 2
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2014:14:54:56 +0200] "GET /xampp/status.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3891
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2014:14:58:04 +0200] "GET /dummies/helloW.php HTTP/1.1" 200 474
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2014:14:58:06 +0200] "GET /dummies/helloW.php HTTP/1.1" 200 474
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2014:14:58:07 +0200] "GET /dummies/helloW.php HTTP/1.1" 200 474

ERROR_log

[Mon Sep 22 14:57:03.001150 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 23774] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Mon Sep 22 14:57:03.001194 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 23774] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Sep 22 14:57:03.001349 2014] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 23774] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Sep 22 14:57:03.009740 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23774] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Sep 22 14:57:03.009786 2014] [core:notice] [pid 23774] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -D SSL -D PHP'
[Mon Sep 22 14:58:22.036884 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23774] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

PHP_ERROR_log

contains nothing....

Comment: erm... is PHP enabled? and is apache running? check the logs

Comment: Doesn't look like PHP is running mate. Check your XAMPP control panel

Comment: Assuming default xampp installation, always look at file `c:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log` to see the error in your php script.

Comment: Or even better, rename `c:\xampp\php\php.ini-development` to `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` and restart apache. You will see your errors in browser.

Comment: I updated the post with some error logs I get,   Where can I find the php.ini-development  file on a linux system ?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP isn't running. Output of

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
```

In an HTML file?

```
Hello World'; ?>
```

Linux? Not my cup of tea. Find out if Apache is running. If it is, Just uninstall and re-install Xampp. It's just Xampp. Unless you're using it in a live environment. In which case, hand in your PHP badge, you're off the force.

P.S. You missed a semicolon after `'Harry'`